# html fixed widths and dynamic layout

Tags: html, css, width, fixed

I have the following code. Is it possible for div_2 to dynamically expand the parent div without the parent div having a width?

```
<div>
    <div id="div_1"></div>
    <div id="div_2"></div>
    <div id="div_3"></div>
</div>

#div_1, #div_2, #div_3{
float:left;
}
#div_1{
width:300px;
}
#div_3{
width:350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you mean but could this be what you want?

```
    #div_1, #div_2, #div_3{
float:left; height: 400px;
}
#div_1{
    width:100px;
    background: red;
}
#div_3{
    width:150px;
    background: blue;
}
#parent{
    border: 4px solid #000;
    float:left;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ndqkg2hq/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its possible. Since you are giving children div some float, so you need to provide overflow to the parent div. It may be overflow hidden. It should work. If still there is some issue with the width, add auto to the width of parent div.

```
.parentdiv{overflow:hidden;width:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible you can try below css for parent div or also you can add .clearfix class into parent div**

```
body > div{overflow:hidden;width:auto;}
```

OR

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
</div>
```

css for .clearfix class

```
.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```